# Why are diagnostics based on the microbiome so slow to adopt?

Tags: research, diagnosis, diagnostics, healthcare-data, gut-microbiota-flora

**Edit** 2023/09/06: Many comments so far raise the fact that we can't tell whether there is causation or correlation between an illness and the corresponding microbiome of the patient. My point isn't to solve that problem, correlation on its own is of interest for facilitating diagnostics: If a patient suffering from an un-diagnosed illness `X` exhibits the a similar biome to that of a patient suffering from a known illness `C`, then the probability that `X = C` is higher than if we didn't have that correlation.

====

The microbiome has been a hot topic for the past decade. This [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ijwzcm-hENU) gives a good overview of this by highlighting how the rise of "modern" chronic diseases is due to a large part to the imbalances in the microbiome following the rise of antibiotics. The old paradigm of single-pathogen to single-remedy is in need of being replaced by a new paradigm where the root causes of the illnesses lie in entire ecosystems rather single pathogens. This incidentally means that AI and big data are likely the way forward in medical diagnostics.

There is at least a dozen companies (e.g., [1](https://www.serestherapeutics.com/), [2](https://www.vedantabio.com/), [3](https://www.ombrelab.com/)) and research groups (e.g., [1](https://knightlab.ucsd.edu/), [2](https://openbiome.org/), [3](https://clinical-microbiomics.com/)) that are making headway in the field. I understand that a lot of this is still at the research stage and that regulatory hurdles only slow things down. However, from what I gather, most of the actionable outcomes from all this work are:

- merely descriptive (rather than prescriptive, i.e., they're basically the equivalent of [23andMe](https://www.23andme.com/), but for the microbiome),
- tailored probiotics or dietary recommendations that claim to "modulate" the microbiome,
- therapeutics of [*Clostridioides difficile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clostridioides_difficile). (The few companies that did get FDA approval and financial traction in microbiome analysis ironically all ended up looking a *C. difficile*.)

I'm probably missing something, but these seem like meager advances compared to the data mining potential of the microbiome. While not dismissing the regulatory and data-sharing challenges, I find it surprising that a systematic data mining of the microbiome hasn't yielded more diagnostic insight in all the aforementioned diseases for which it is known to be relevant.

At the risk of sounding naive, why is microbiome sampling (which is relatively unintrusive) not used systematically by hospitals to profile various illnesses? Such data would be a gold mine of insight as opposed to the vary basic tests commonly done (e.g., blood tests or imaging). (Even fecal sampling, to my knowledge, is very rarely used.)

Comment: Part of the problem is that its only been in the past 10-15 years that microbiome analysis has been easy and cheap, and it still costs in the $100/sample range, even if you have a sequencer . Another part of it is that this sort of analysis hasn't been validated for clinical use. You might find [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cmi.2019.04.019) of some interest.

Comment: re: your edit - what are the cases you know about where there is evidence that the microbiome specifically provides additional diagnostic information, above and beyond what is typically used? Not just where it is associated with something, but where it is shown useful in diagnosis.

Comment: re: your edit - You've made an erroneous statement/assumption. You're not medically trained or qualified to state that correlation is important (or "interesting") for diagnosing illnesses. Just because you wish it to be so does not mean it is true.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Did you even understand the edit? If so, can you try to rephrase it in your own words?

Comment: @BryanKrause One case would be obesity, but there are many more examples, cf. this talk at minute 5:12: https://youtu.be/Ijwzcm-hENU?t=312

Comment: @Tfovid - Don't be so patronizing. I've practiced medicine for decades. You watched a video. Until we have more *evidence* (not *correlation*), that is all we have: correlation. Maybe even *coincidence*. Maybe something else entirely is affecting both the body and the microbiome. You have nothing here to tie your high horse to. You're not correct because you wish to be.

Comment: @Tfovid Why would you need a microbiome to diagnose obesity when a scale works?

Comment: @BryanKrause Because it's a lot more accurate than a scale.

Comment: @Tfovid A lot more accurate? Based on what?

Comment: @BryanKrause ... based on the classification metrics in that study mentioned by Rob Knight. That's why I sent it to you when you asked for examples. It is 90% accurate when based on the microbiome versus 57% based on the human biome. In this case, it is indeed a trivial example in that a simple BMI measurement would be more than enough, but my point was to highlight the relevance of the microbiome in diagnostics.

Comment: @Tfovid I'm not going to watch a video where someone can claim whatever they want, where's the paper and the citation? What about the comparison to a scale? It sounds like that's not there, is it? No one is doing obesity diagnosis using the human biome, so why would that be the comparison? If you can do a simple BMI measurement instead of an expensive test, why does this highlight the relevance rather than emphasizing the irrelevance for this purpose? Doesn't that directly answer why it's not being used for diagnosis: it doesn't beat a simple BMI measurement?

Comment: @BryanKrause If a change in the microbiome causes a change in behaviour, doesn't that mean that looking at the microbiome should be part of the diagnostic process? https://www.nature.com/articles/s41522-021-00193-9 As for the "video where someone can claim whatever they want", that someone is the PI of the Knight Lab (cf. the peer-reviewed publications therein: knightlab.ucsd.edu/)

Comment: That's not how diagnosis works. Diagnosis relies on what's measurable. There's no need for diagnostic markers to be early in the casual chain, they are most often distal to the disease: "symptoms".

Comment: @BryanKrause In that case, i.e., if the problem lies in my lack of understanding of how diagnosis works, could you please expand on your last comment with a full-fledged answer to the OP? The microbiome is measurable in the sense that it boils down to statistical profiles that can be compared with degrees of probability (and uncertainty) with those of patients suffering from various illnesses. I therefore don't understand why you say that it's not measurable.

Comment: And costs more than stepping on a scale. And doesn't actually measure *obesity*, which involves carrying too much weight. I think I've explained it well enough in the comments, you're asking why something isn't used for a thing when you haven't found anything to suggest it would be more useful for that thing than other measures.

Answer (score 5):

I've been following microbiomes since they first began to be discussed, and remember the first fecal transplant done for treatment of C. diff. Now it's a [common enough treatment](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/stool-transplants-are-now-standard-of-care-for-recurrent-c-difficile-infections-2019050916576). But when [an average weight woman with C.diff had a transfer from her daughter, who was obese, became obese](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4438885/), that was really astonishing (this was in 2015). By then, many researchers in the US and the EU were doing microbiome studies.

> The NIH funded Human Microbiome Project (HMP) Consortium has established a population-scale framework which catalyzed significant development of metagenomic protocols resulting in a broad range of quality-controlled resources and data including standardized methods for creating, processing and interpreting distinct types of high-throughput metagenomic data available to the scientific community. Here we present resources from a population of 242 healthy adults sampled at 15 to 18 body sites up to three times, which to date, have generated 5,177 microbial taxonomic profiles from 16S rRNA genes and over 3.5 Tb of metagenomic sequence.

That was  in 2012. The NIH is still funding the HMP.

I'm not how sure how quickly you think research can/should be done, but so far, there has been a correllation between [gut microbiota](https://gut.bmj.com/content/71/5/1020?fbclid=IwAR1ejIqGKV1qFnJ5AVFQeJcUntqnMYt1X1GimbxgKP1-S3bPJDV4kzW5DUg) and intestinal bowel diseases, coeliac disease, irritable bowel syndrome, colorectal cancer, chronic liver diseases, pancreatic disorders/cancer, liver cirrhosis, obesity, type 2 diabetes and non-alcoholic fatty liver disease among others.

But which came first, the chicken or the egg? We know the answer for Helicobacter pylori and obesity, but not for the rest. That would require, among other things, longitudinal studies starting at birth, which would involve unimaginable expense.

> ...why is microbiome sampling (which is relatively unintrusive) not used systematically by hospitals to profile various illnesses?

The gut alone is populated by from 10^7 to 10^14 microorganisms. Hospitals do not have [money coming out the wazoo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yFFyW4Ad8k), nor are they equipped to do that kind of analysis. For that matter (money), neither do most governments, which is why many countries have [national debts](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-by-national-debt). Money is needed for those studies, and it must come from a limited budget. Increased spending in one area means decreased spending in another, or more borrowing.

> This incidentally means that AI and big data are likely the way forward in medical diagnostics.

Please know that as little as I know about AI, I do know that it is abysmal when it comes to health/medicine. IBM spent many billions on Watson (unintentionally very well named) with the goal of improving health care. It's been pretty much a disaster, with Watson scoring at or below the proficiency of second year medical students, beating them in two areas only: diagnosis of breast and (I think) lung cancer, but never reaching the proficiency of the lowly first year resident. MD Anderson spent $95M on Watson but trashed it because it just wasn't adding anything to health care except more work and headaches. But I am not fluent in AI, so, hey, who knows?

<sub>[A framework for human microbiome research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3377744/)</sub>

Comment: That last paragraph is actually what astonishes me here. I don't know what kind of blunders they made with Watson, but coming from a data science background, the fact that the microbiome isn't systematically looked at by modern AI---given the fact that it is a big data problem by definition---seems like a major oversight to me. AI now isn't the AI from 2012.

Comment: Great answer. Agree with the point about correlation. AFAIK we have only correlated changes in microbiome with disease; causation (or whether the microbiome is altered because of disease rather than the other way around) remains to be demonstrated, reducing usefulness for diagnosis.

Comment: @Tfovid - Do you think IBM, having spent 200 billion dollars on Watson so far, haven't used data scientists? AI is just that: artificial. They sold Watson Health at a great loss. I'm sure they tried their best. But as I said, I am not very familiar with AI. AI in languages is great. In medicine? not so much, even in 2023.

Comment: @anongoodnurse IBM Watson is a flop because it aimed at general intelligence with antiquated technology (by AI standards). The gut microbiome, despite the thousands of bacterial species is a much more limited problem. I don't know how they went about it, but if everybody agrees on the relevance of the microbiome in health, then a better application of AI to such a supervised learning problem should (and will) surely unravel all the correlations between illnesses and the biome.

Comment: @Tfovid AI doesn't care for Occam's Razor, and doesn't know when to do a controlled trial. I get why you're excited, but your description of what it would do hits the nail on the head: correlation does not imply causation. (AI today _is_ basically AI from 2012, outside a few narrow areas.) This would be useful for helping find research hypotheses, but probably not useful as a diagnostic. (Or maybe it would be: who knows?)

Comment: Capabilities of 'AI' isn't the only problem. Even if you ignore all the problems with actual analysis, and assume you have a magic box, you still have a huge logistical/engineering challenge performing the capture of the microbiome in a way that generates digital data that can be processed by AI system to perform diagnostics. There's a reason the deployment of 'AI' systems in healthcare has been focused on operational and radiology workflows. These are the fields that already work with primarily digital data.

Comment: And if you want to apply it to research: Look at the average size of a datapoint, 14 gigabytes per individual average. Consider how big a training set with enough individuals for machine learning to be reliable, with enough data to cover demographic and regional noise. You'd be looking at PB to EB to be gathered.

Comment: @Tfovid - I understand your reaction regarding the future of medicine and AI. I was sincerely hoping AI would help; I didn't feel threatened by a technology that might help patients better than I/other doctors can. But I think you're not taking into account the serious drawback that *correlation does not mean causation* presents. Seriously, the only way to determine that is either with longitudinal studies showing the same microorganism(s) causing the same diseases (at an astronomical expense: many hundreds of thousands of people would need to have stool analyses at least yearly from birth...

Comment: ...and such studies are rife with complications (has the pt. taken antibiotics within 3-6 months of the sample? Etc.), or we would need to do hundreds of thousands of fecal transplants on human guinea pigs, which is not allowed. Also, it's very difficult to alter gut microbiomes more than temporarily; they are incredibly complex ecosystems. Finally, the microbiome is complicated by the genetics, behavior, diet, and the other microbiomes of the human it inhabits (e.g. dental carries). I'm not saying we'll never get there, but it won't happen in my lifetime, and maybe not in yours, either.

Comment: @Tfovid The Gut microbiome is still a much bigger problem than the kinds of problems that deployable medical AI currently addresses. The state of the art in systematic use is more things like nodule and bleed detection, automating things that are well understood parts of medical diagnosis.

Comment: In physiotherapy, evidence suggests that new scientific knowledge takes about 13-17 years until it found its way into regular, wide-spread practice. I do fear that it is not any different in other medical disciplines. Taking this as a given, we cannot expect that to become common practice before the 2030s.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking - Taking the history of medicine from the beginning, 15 years is lightening fast! There's a saying in medicine: "Be neither first nor last." Alexander Pope is the author: "Be not the first by whom the new are tried, Nor yet the last to lay the old aside." In medicine, it's wise to wait a bit to see how a drug/treatment does before imposing it on your own patients. It's not based in fear, it's based in wisdom and care for your patient. In this case, we have only correlation, which means little.